# OpenGL solid color displayed instead of texture

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, textures

So, I have looked at all similar questions in this website and others, and I failed to find an answer to why my texture fails to load. I'm sure the texture is read properly, however, it is just not applied correctly. Here's my code:

Getting the texture:

```
 glGenTextures(NumTextures, textures);

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );

// load and bind tree texture
readPPM6("textures/tree_trunk.pbm", treeTex);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, treeTex);
```

Binding the object:

```
// VAO[Tree]
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vElements[TreeE]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*treeIndices.size(), treeIndices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(vArrays[TreeA]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffers[TreeB]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*treeVertices.size() + sizeof(vec2) * 90, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat)*treeVertices.size(), treeVertices.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*treeVertices.size(), sizeof(vec2)*90,
    treeTexCoords);
glUseProgram( texture );
vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( texture, "vPosition" );
glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
vTexCoord = glGetAttribLocation( texture, "vTexCoord" );
glVertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
    (const void*) ((sizeof(GLfloat) * treeVertices.size())));
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord ); 
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(texture, "texture"), 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Drawing the tree:

```
glUseProgram(texture);

proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(texture, "projection");
model_view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(texture, "modelview");
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, projmat);
glUniformMatrix4fv(model_view_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, modelmat);

glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xFFFF);

glBindVertexArray(vArrays[TreeA]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vElements[TreeE]);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 ); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, treeIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glUseProgram(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The way the tree was created:

```
getCylinderVertices(treeVertices, 10.0, 3.0, 10);
getCylinderIndices(treeIndices, 10);

getConeVertices(treeVertices, 10.0, 15.0, 6.0, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    treeIndices.push_back(60+i*3);
    treeIndices.push_back(60+i*3+1);
    treeIndices.push_back(60+i*3+2);
    treeIndices.push_back(0xFFFF);
}

treeTexCoords = new vec2[90];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    treeTexCoords[i*6] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    treeTexCoords[i*6+1] = vec2(0.0, 0.2);
    treeTexCoords[i*6+2] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    treeTexCoords[i*6+3] = vec2(1.0, 0.2);
    treeTexCoords[i*6+4] = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
    treeTexCoords[i*6+5] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    treeTexCoords[60+i] = vec2(0.0,0.0);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
    #version 330 core

attribute vec4 vPosition;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main() 
{ 
    texCoord    = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = projection*modelview*vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
 #version 330 core

in  vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() 
{ 
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
}
```

After fixing a buffer subdata allocation problem, this is how the trees look at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kmwf.jpg

For reference this is the image I'm using:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJxk.jpg

I have solved the final problem, the reader was reading an endline as part of the image, thus everything was shifted to the next color. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If you change the tree_trunk.pbm image, does the tree color change? to ensure the file itself is loaded and used in the shader).
Also, try changing the fragment shader to display the uv, to ensure the texCoords are correctly set: gl_FragColor = vec4(texCoord.x, texCoord.y, 1.0, 1.0);

Comment: The color changes when the image changes. When I change the frag color as you suggested everything becomes blue. So, somehow I guess all u,v is set as 0.0, 0.0 or the texture coordinates are not created. How can I make sure the coordinates are set correctly?

Comment: Have you tried removing the unused "vertex" and "normal" attribute from your shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised this code is not causing a crash, `sizeof (vec2) * 90` is what you should be using in the second call to `glBufferSubData (...)` since the number of floating-point components in your texture coordinate array is half the number of components in your vertex position array. You are overrunning both the VBO's storage and your texture coordinate array in client memory when you fill the buffer with data.

`sizeof (treeTexCoords)` is definitely not what you want, because you have dynamically allocated that array! While you can use `sizeof (...)` to get the size of a statically sized array if you try to do it with a pointer to memory allocated with `new`, all you will get is the size of the pointer itself. Thus, `sizeof (treeTexCoords)` is probably **4** or **8** on your system.

```
glBindVertexArray (vArrays [TreeA]);
glBindBuffer      (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffers [TreeB]);

//
// @CORRECTION #1
//
glBufferData      (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (GLfloat) * treeVertices.size () + 
                                    sizeof (vec2)    * 90,
                                        NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData   (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,
                                    sizeof (GLfloat) * treeVertices.size (),
                                        treeVertices.data ());
//
// @CORRECTION #2
//
glBufferSubData   (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (GLfloat) * treeVertices.size (), 
                                    sizeof (vec2)    * 90,
                                        treeTexCoords);
```

Correction #1 allocates the appropriate amount of storage (instead of enough storage for all of your vertices + 1 pointer).

Correction #2 reads only up to the end of `treeTexCoords` instead of overrunning it.

There may be additional issues depending on how `treeVertices` is declared - can you edit your question to show the declaration of `treeVertices`? I am assuming it is something like `std::vector <GLfloat>`.

Comment: Yep, I have realized this problem yesterday and fixed it, and yes treeVertices is a vector, I will post the image I now get, maybe there is actually something wrong with me reading the image.